# Pytorch UnpicklingError: A load persistent id instruction was encountered

Tags: python, pytorch

My dataloader raises this error when loading its files:

```
UnpicklingError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-cb081a68afbe> in <module>
----> 1 torch.load("/network/tmp1/ccai/data/labelbox_2020/imgs/AB_304.png")

~/.conda/envs/omnienv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/serialization.py in load(f, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
    593                     return torch.jit.load(opened_file)
    594                 return _load(opened_zipfile, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
--> 595         return _legacy_load(opened_file, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
    596 
    597 

~/.conda/envs/omnienv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/serialization.py in _legacy_load(f, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
    762             "functionality.")
    763 
--> 764     magic_number = pickle_module.load(f, **pickle_load_args)
    765     if magic_number != MAGIC_NUMBER:
    766         raise RuntimeError("Invalid magic number; corrupt file?")

UnpicklingError: A load persistent id instruction was encountered,
but no persistent_load function was specified.
```

What's bugging me is that I'm not doing multiple loads from the same process as pointed out [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/45136).

Could it be that this error is triggered by multiple python processes reading the same file?

pytorch 1.7 on ubuntu 18 with python 3.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it: this error can be triggered when using `torch.load` on the wrong type of data, a `.png` image in this case.